# In which package is the more_suggestions.scope located and what does it do?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses, scopes, smartscopes

I can see that there are several scopes in Ubuntu 14.04 like

> searchin.scope web.scope books.scope news.scope more_suggestions.scope
>   recipes.scope

etc.

What functions do these scopes perform? And which package contains these scopes?

Comment: We live by upvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All scopes are in the package

```
unity-scopes-master-default
```

---

Explanation, eg:

```
apt-file search searchin.scope
apt-file search recipes.scope 
[..]
```

---

### Scopes

A new generation of mobile experiences
Build more than just apps

Ubuntu enables the delivery of content and services directly to the screen – effectively creating a rich, fast and unfragmented experience for users, while giving developers the unprecedented opportunity to create app-like experiences that are integral to the device, at a fraction of the cost to build and maintain traditional apps. These experiences are developed using Ubuntu Scopes, a new UI toolkit available through the Ubuntu SDK.

Scopes are a complete reinvention of the content and services experience. Users have a new way to access content and apps without having to download individual apps – and developers have the opportunity to be discovered via the device’s categorized home screens. There are two types of scopes:

**Aggregation Scopes** – these define the device’s default experience by bringing together content and services from multiple sources and delivering them as a unified experience. For example, the video scope will display multiple video sources, and similarly a music scope can display music related content from a variety of providers. Each source can expand into an app-like, fully branded experience (branded scopes).

**Branded Scopes** – app-like experiences delivered directly to the screen. This is the fastest path to develop a rich mobile experience on Ubuntu, with higher discoverability and easier to develop and maintain than traditional apps. By attributing categories (music, news, videos, etc) to your branded Scopes, users can discover them from both the default aggregation Scopes and the Store. They can become integral to the device’s default experience once a user favorites your branded scope.

It’s a world away from traditional smartphones and the app icon grid, and brings a great opportunity for developers to shine.

[Source](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/scopes/)